# Unable to click on the internet tab

Tags: css, selenium, xpath

I have an element as you can see from the below image

[Internet tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHKAS.jpg)

It is not getting clicked. I tried with both linktext and xpath but it is not working. Here is the xpath: `.//*[@id='service-menu-list']/ul/li[3]/a`

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='service-menu-list']/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
```

Can you please let me know what am I missing? I have also added a explicit wait before the element loads.

Comment: Share `HTML` code for the same and **all** your attempts to locate element including one with explicit wait. Also share exception log

Comment: Please make it a point to provide URL of the page, when you post something like this.